# can you call the alt tag for an image dynamically?

Tags: images

I need to call the alt tag for images on my site dynamically.  The only thing I can find online is to use the post title function but that doesn't really help me out.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail? What images do you want to provide dynamic ALT tags? What dynamic data do you want to provide as ALT tags?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the *alt* attribute of the image is stored in `post_content`, isn't it?

To get the alt tag for an image with attachment ID `$attachment_ID`, you would just call:

```
$alt_text = get_post( $attachment_ID )->post_content;
```

To actually display the alt text dynamically on images that are already embedded in posts, you would have to do some heavy regex processing on `the_content` filter.

If you wanted to set it dynamically when adding the image to a post, I would add a filter on `image_send_to_editor`.